# intro to x86 assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, intel

I'm looking over an example on assembly in CSAPP (Computer Systems - A programmer's Perspective 2nd) and I just want to know if my understanding of the assembly code is correct.

Practice problem 3.23

```
int fun_b(unsigned x) {
   int val = 0;
   int i;
   for ( ____;_____;_____) {
   }
   return val;
}
```

The gcc C compiler generates the following assembly code:

```
x at %ebp+8
// what I've gotten so far

1 movl 8(%ebp), %ebx  // ebx: x
2 movl $0, %eax  // eax: val, set to 0 since eax is where the return 
// value is stored and val is being returned at the end
3 movl $0, %ecx  // ecx: i, set to 0
4 .L13:  // loop
5 leal (%eax,%eax), %edx  // edx = val+val 
6 movl %ebx, %eax  // val = x (?)
7 andl $1, %eax // x = x & 1
8 orl %edx, %eax  // x = (val+val) | (x & 1)
9 shrl %ebx Shift right by 1  // x = x >> 1
10 addl $1, %ecx  // i++
11 cmpl $32, %ecx  // if i < 32 jump back to loop
12 jne .L13
```

There was a similar post on the same problem with the solution, but I'm looking for more of a walk-through  and explanation of the assembly code line by line.

Comment: What?  SO is not an x86-32 assembler manual!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already seem to have the meaning of the instructions figured out. The comment on lines `7-8` are slightly wrong however, because those assign to `eax` which is `val` not `x`:

```
7 andl $1, %eax // val = val & 1 = x & 1
8 orl %edx, %eax  // val = (val+val) | (x & 1)
```

Putting this into the C template could be:

```
for(i = 0; i < 32; i++, x >>= 1) {
    val = (val + val) | (x & 1);
}
```

Note that `(val + val)` is just a left shift, so what this function is doing is shifting out bits from `x` on the right and shifting them in into `val` from the right. As such, it's mirroring the bits.

PS: if the body of the `for` must be empty you can of course merge it into the third expression.